# Php , Mysql Select from table where row = ? it is possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Hello I want to get select query with send row record number

```
 $row = 3;
 SELECT FROM clients WHERE ROW()=$row ORDER BY ID DESC
```

it is possible ? How can i do that ?

Comment: Thanks guys for good answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the third row, use `offset`/`limit`:

```
select *
from clients
order by id
offset 2
limit 1;
```

Note that that `offset 0` gets the first record, so offset 2 would be the third record.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LIMIT` instead of `WHERE`

If you want get a row with N position, you can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT N-1,1
```

So if you want get third row you need to use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 2,1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do.. entry_id is unique and 1 = first row, 2 = second row, etc..

```
entry_id is set as primary index and auto increase..

entry_id | what | ever | records
1 | a | b | c
2 | a | b | c
3 | b | c | a
4 | a | b | c
5 | a | b | c

$row = 3;

Select * From clients Where entry_id = $row
```

returns third row, 3, b, c, a